# Is there a way to determine why clang-format is indenting?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is there a way to tell why clang-format is indenting a portion of code? I can't seem to figure out which style option to update.

Here is the unformatted code:

```
#define MY_PROTECTED protected

class MyClass {
public:
  void myMethod();

MY_PROTECTED:
  int myMember;
};
```

After running clang-format (10.0) with -style=Google, I get the following output:

```
#define MY_PROTECTED protected

class MyClass {
 public:
  void myMethod();

  MY_PROTECTED : int myMember;
};
```

I even tried using comments to turn clang format off/on, but it still isn't quite correct:

```
#define MY_PROTECTED protected

class MyClass {
 public:
  void myMethod();

  // clang-format off
MY_PROTECTED:
      // clang-format on
      int myMember;
};
```

Comment: Looks like it's reading your macro as part of public. In the second example, the int is seen as part of the line containing `MY_PROTECTED`, so it's further indented. If you avoid the pointless macro, there is no problem. I get that this likely just MRE code, but the MRE should be representative of your problem. clang-format's parsing is surface-level, it's not running a pre-processor and then formatting.

Comment: Unrelated, but IMHO `#define MY_PROTECTED protected` is a bad idea™ from a code readability standpoint.